# How to target more than one element while using operators for an onclick event

Tags: jquery

Here I would like to target more than one element for an onClick event while also disabling all buttons apart from the one that has been clicked.

So far I have this:

```
 $("#elementone", "elementtwo, #elementthree").on('click', function(){
              if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#elementone, #elementtwo, #elementthree').attr('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

The code below does what I want however I was hoping there would be a more elegant way to achieve this?

```
$("#elementone").on('click', function(){
              if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#elementtwo, #elementthree').attr('disabled', true);
   }
}); 

$("elementtwo").on('click', function(){
              if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#elementone, #elementthree').attr('disabled', true);
   }
}); 

$("#elementthree").on('click', function(){
              if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#elementone, #elementtwo').attr('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class` instead of `id` That is, place a class named "element" (or any other valid class name) on the three buttons. Then you can use:

```
var $elements = $('.element');
$elements.click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $elements.not(this).prop('disabled', true);
   }
});
```

Notes:

1. The call to [`.not(this)`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) removes the currently clicked button from the set.
2. You should also use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), instead of `.attr()` to disable the buttons.
3. If these are `<input type="checkbox">` elements, it would be better to use the `change` event, instead of the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elementone,#elementtwo,#elementthree").on('click', function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr("id"),
        selectors = {
            elementone: "#elementtwo,#elementthree",
            elementtwo: "#elementone,#elementthree",
            elementthree: "#elementone,#elementtwo"
        },
        selector = selectors[clickedId];

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(selector).attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```